# How to execute a full matlab script in R Studio?

Tags: r, matlab

I would like to run a full existing Matlab script (main script including loop over multiple files) in R. 
Using the matlabr package, I cannot find a way to **not** automatically open the Matlab interface each time the script is executed; but this slows down my R model a lot.

the R script looks like this:

```
library(matlabr)
if(have_matlab())
{ get_matlab(try_defaults = TRUE, desktop = FALSE, splash = FALSE, display = FALSE, wait = TRUE}

while (t < total.year ) {            # my R script runs over multiple years
  # pre-calculations
  ...
  <<change-some-files.txt>>         # these are later used by the matlab script
  ... 
  # run matlab
  system("matlab -wait -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r \"run('<<here-the-full-path-name-of-the-matlap-script.m>>'); exit\"")
}
```

While it seems to me that this system command does not ask to open Matlab, running this R script results in a Matlab pop-up which automatically opens and closes at each time step. This obviously slows down the whole process.
Is there a way to avoid this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're starting up a new instance of MATLAB every time round your R `while` loop, and MATLAB takes some time to start up whether or not you want it to display an interface.

To avoid this you could:

- rewrite your code so that the looping takes place in your MATLAB script - if the `pre-calculations` code can't easily be translated from R to MATLAB then you could see if it's quicker to call that R code from within the MATLAB loop, not vice versa
- keep MATLAB open and use some communication method to call the script each time round the R loop - for example you could try the [R.matlab](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/R.matlab.pdf) package
- if you have a licence for [MATLAB Compiler](https://uk.mathworks.com/products/compiler.html), compile your MATLAB code to an executable, which (I think) should start up faster.